# Why so many down votes on this: "Is it possible to Alt-Tab in Windows 8?"

Tags: discussion

[Is it possible to Alt-Tab in Windows 8?](https://superuser.com/questions/713474/is-it-possible-to-alt-tab-in-windows-8) Has at this time -8 points.  Now it's not exactly the most complex question, but I don't see anything wrong with it. It's not a duplicate, it's not off topic, it's just small. I went to the edit history and I see that it's original form was somewhat less helpful, but even after being fixed it's getting voted down.

So what's wrong with it? Isn't this a question many people might want an answer too before switching to Windows 8? Might they search for the answer and find it here?

Comment: Hovering the downvote arrow reveals the tool tip: *This question does not show any research effort, [...]*. I can imagine that many users consider this question trivial to research.

Comment: Did you read [the original post](http://superuser.com/revisions/713474/1)?

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion, it's just too obvious. Alt-Tab has been in since Windows 3.0, and I don't think Microsoft would ever even consider removing it. :P

Comment: The Start Menu had been in since Windows 95, and I didn't think Microsoft would ever even consider removing it. Until they did.

Comment: True. Although, Windows 8 and 8.1 seem to be optimized for tablets as well as desktops and laptops. So, yeah.

Comment: @crayzeedude How do you alt-tab on a touchscreen?

Comment: I'm assuming in Windows 8.1? If so, have the 'Add the standard keyboard layout as a touch keyboard option' setting enabled, enable the touch keyboard, swap to the standard layout, then press either ALT button, then TAB.

Answer (score -2):

It's because they did not put adequate research into it before posting. If they had done a simple Google search, they would have found their answer.

Comment: This was already shared but in a nicer way.

Comment: Not as an answer, however. And the other answer is incorrect.

Comment: I have edited my post to sound nicer.